# Hibernate @OneToMany ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, constraints

The problem is that I want to have the possibility of having the same parachute_id for different reservations but when I save reservation which have the same parachute_id I get:
`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '78' for key 'parachute_id'`

That's my code:

```
@OneToMany  
@JoinTable(name="reservation_parachute")  
Collection<Parachute> parachute = new ArrayList<Parachute>();
```

And database example:

`Reservation_id parachute_id

130              76

129              75

127              51

127              63

126              10

126               2

126               1

131              77

133              78`

Comment: Need more details - post a result of 'show create table' for this table from db

Comment: According http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/exception/ConstraintViolationException.html you have an error on the Database layer. Think something wrong with your schema.

Comment: it's impossible because db can't have two rows with the same id. You need to change your database schema

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing `@OneToMany` with `@ManyToMany`.

Read it like this:

`One` Reservation 'owns' `Many` Parachute

But you want something like:

`Many` Reservation 'share' `Many` Parachute

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are describing you do not need a many-to-many join table.

For a parachute to have different reservations i would do:

in Resrvation.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parachuteID")
private Parachute parachute;
```

in Parachute.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parachute")
private List<Reservation> reservations;
```

This way a parachute will have a list of reservations.

Comment: Parachute knowing about Reservation is a bad design.

Comment: That is up to the OP to decide, in any case you can remove the list of Reservation from Parachute and keep only the Parachute on the Reservation